# How to detect the swipe left or Right in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I have an `EditText` view in android. On this I want to detect swipe left or right. I am able to get it on an empty space using the code below. But this does not work when I swipe on an `EditText`. How do I do that? Please let me know If I am doing something wrong. Thank you.

Code Used:

```
switch (touchevent.getAction())
{
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    {
        oldTouchValue = touchevent.getX();
        break;
    }
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    {
        float currentX = touchevent.getX();
        if (oldTouchValue < currentX)
        {
            // swiped left
        }
        if (oldTouchValue > currentX )
        {
            swiped right
        }
    break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Helpful tutorial for this requiement http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/use-androids-gesture-detector-to-translate-a-swipe-into-an-event/

Answer (score 120, accepted):

**Simplest left to right swipe detector:**

In your activity class add following attributes:

```
private float x1,x2;
static final int MIN_DISTANCE = 150;
```

and override `onTouchEvent()` method:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{     
    switch(event.getAction())
    {
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
          x1 = event.getX();                          
      break;          
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
          x2 = event.getX();
          float deltaX = x2 - x1;
          if (Math.abs(deltaX) > MIN_DISTANCE)
          {
              Toast.makeText(this, "left2right swipe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
          }
          else
          {
              // consider as something else - a screen tap for example
          }                       
      break;    
    }            
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);        
}
```

Comment: thanks it works but can you please tell me how to make it work if there's a scrollView?

Comment: As `getAction()` returns mixed data of both action type and pointer index, it wouldn't be better to use `getActionMasked()`, that only returns action type?

Comment: This solution is dated. Now you can use onFling gesture.

Comment: @LS_ Think about customizing ScrollView and put onInterceptTouchEvent to manage what events should reach the child views.

Answer (score 64):

I like the code from @user2999943. But just some minor changes for my own purposes.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{     
    switch(event.getAction())
    {
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
          x1 = event.getX();                         
      break;         
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
          x2 = event.getX();
          float deltaX = x2 - x1;

          if (Math.abs(deltaX) > MIN_DISTANCE)
          {
              // Left to Right swipe action
              if (x2 > x1)
              {
                  Toast.makeText(this, "Left to Right swipe [Next]", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();                     
              }

              // Right to left swipe action               
              else 
              {
                  Toast.makeText(this, "Right to Left swipe [Previous]", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();                    
              }

          }
          else
          {
              // consider as something else - a screen tap for example
          }                          
      break;   
    }           
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);       
}
```

Comment: Hey, it seems that when this code is in an activity with a ScrollView, it doesn't work. Any idea why? Great code otherwise

Comment: Jona, the same View has to be able to pickup the ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_UP events for this to work.

Comment: @AlWang what do you mean?

Comment: It seems that in Jona's case, the ScrollView is intercepting the MotionEvent. You should look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12884250/motionevent-handling-in-scrollview-in-android for an implementation.

Comment: can you tell me how to detect up and down swipe also

Comment: Hi Maulik, I am not really an Android DEV, this is something I wrote a long time ago. I imagine it would end up looking something like this, please note I cannot test this, merely what I think it would end up looking like: https://gist.github.com/drpain/299a4d51bfb9ffeff2206a37e09dcc6b 

You might need to reverse the logic on line 40 if it's the wrong way around.

Answer (score 37):

This is a cute class I use 
(in cases I want to catch event on a View, if it is a ViewGroup, I use the second implementation):

```
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class SwipeDetector implements View.OnTouchListener{

    private int min_distance = 100;
    private float downX, downY, upX, upY;
    private View v;

    private onSwipeEvent swipeEventListener;



    public SwipeDetector(View v){
        this.v=v;
        v.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    public void setOnSwipeListener(onSwipeEvent listener)
    {
        try{
            swipeEventListener=listener;
        }
        catch(ClassCastException e)
        {
            Log.e("ClassCastException","please pass SwipeDetector.onSwipeEvent Interface instance",e);
        }
    }


    public void onRightToLeftSwipe(){
        if(swipeEventListener!=null)
            swipeEventListener.SwipeEventDetected(v,SwipeTypeEnum.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
        else
            Log.e("SwipeDetector error","please pass SwipeDetector.onSwipeEvent Interface instance");
    }

    public void onLeftToRightSwipe(){
        if(swipeEventListener!=null)
            swipeEventListener.SwipeEventDetected(v,SwipeTypeEnum.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
        else
            Log.e("SwipeDetector error","please pass SwipeDetector.onSwipeEvent Interface instance");
    }

    public void onTopToBottomSwipe(){
        if(swipeEventListener!=null)
            swipeEventListener.SwipeEventDetected(v,SwipeTypeEnum.TOP_TO_BOTTOM);
        else
            Log.e("SwipeDetector error","please pass SwipeDetector.onSwipeEvent Interface instance");
    }

    public void onBottomToTopSwipe(){
        if(swipeEventListener!=null)
            swipeEventListener.SwipeEventDetected(v,SwipeTypeEnum.BOTTOM_TO_TOP);
        else
            Log.e("SwipeDetector error","please pass SwipeDetector.onSwipeEvent Interface instance");
    }

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch(event.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            downX = event.getX();
            downY = event.getY();
            return true;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
            upX = event.getX();
            upY = event.getY();

            float deltaX = downX - upX;
            float deltaY = downY - upY;

            //HORIZONTAL SCROLL
            if(Math.abs(deltaX) > Math.abs(deltaY))
            {
                if(Math.abs(deltaX) > min_distance){
                    // left or right
                    if(deltaX < 0) 
                    {
                        this.onLeftToRightSwipe();
                        return true;
                    }
                    if(deltaX > 0) {
                        this.onRightToLeftSwipe();
                        return true; 
                    }
                }
                else {
                    //not long enough swipe...
                    return false; 
                }
            }
            //VERTICAL SCROLL
            else 
            {
                if(Math.abs(deltaY) > min_distance){
                    // top or down
                    if(deltaY < 0) 
                    { this.onTopToBottomSwipe();
                    return true; 
                    }
                    if(deltaY > 0)
                    { this.onBottomToTopSwipe(); 
                    return true;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    //not long enough swipe...
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
        }
        return false;
    }
    public interface onSwipeEvent
    {
        public void SwipeEventDetected(View v, SwipeTypeEnum SwipeType);
    }

    public SwipeDetector setMinDistanceInPixels(int min_distance)
{
    this.min_distance=min_distance;
    return this;
}

    public enum SwipeTypeEnum
    {
        RIGHT_TO_LEFT,LEFT_TO_RIGHT,TOP_TO_BOTTOM,BOTTOM_TO_TOP
    }

}
```

and this is a use example:

```
filters_container=(RelativeLayout)root.findViewById(R.id.filters_container);
    new SwipeDetector(filters_container).setOnSwipeListener(new SwipeDetector.onSwipeEvent() {
        @Override
        public void SwipeEventDetected(View v, SwipeDetector.SwipeTypeEnum swipeType) {
            if(swipeType==SwipeDetector.SwipeTypeEnum.LEFT_TO_RIGHT)
                getActivity().onBackPressed();
        }
    });
```

---

In some cases you would like to detect the swipe gestures on a container and pass down the touch Events to the childs so in that case you can create a Custom View group, lets say RelativeLayout and override onInterceptTouchEvent , and there you can detect the swipe event without blocking the pass of Touch Event to your child views,for Example:

```
    import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;


public class SwipeDetectRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout {


    private float x1,x2;
    static final int MIN_DISTANCE=150;
    private onSwipeEventDetected mSwipeDetectedListener;


    public SwipeDetectRelativeLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SwipeDetectRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SwipeDetectRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

        switch(ev.getAction())
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                x1 = ev.getX();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                x2 = ev.getX();
                float deltaX = x2 - x1;
                if (Math.abs(deltaX) > MIN_DISTANCE)
                {
                        //swiping right to left
                        if(deltaX<0)
                        {
                            if(mSwipeDetectedListener!=null)
                                mSwipeDetectedListener.swipeEventDetected();
                        }
                }
                break;
        }
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    public interface onSwipeEventDetected
    {
        public void swipeEventDetected();
    }

    public void registerToSwipeEvents(onSwipeEventDetected listener)
    {
        this.mSwipeDetectedListener=listener;
    }
}
```

Comment: excellent implementation, I've used the first option and also added support for onTouch, so I have next previous and onTouch covered, thanks!

Comment: @Gal Rom How to use the second method?

Comment: Excellent answer! It definitely works with very little effort and super effectively.

Comment: Awesome implementation.

Comment: For me, this gives incorrect SWIPE_LEFT, SWIPE_RIGHT events even if I swipe vertically!! (I have attached SwipeDetector to my recycleview). Also made my recycle view sluggish on vertical scrolling!

Comment: Isn't it possible to directly get SWIPE events from android system rather than explicitely creating them by calculation?

Answer (score 9):

Swipe events are a kind of `onTouch` events. Simply simplifying @Gal Rom 's answer, just keep track of the vertical an horizontal deltas, and with a little math you can determine what kind of swipe a touchEvent was. (Again, let me stress that this was OBSENELY based to a previous answer, but the simplicity may appeal to novices). The idea is to extend an OnTouchListener, detect what kind of swipe (touch) just happened and call specific methods for each kind.

```
public class SwipeListener implements View.OnTouchListener {
    private int min_distance = 100;
    private float downX, downY, upX, upY;
    View v;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        this.v = v;
        switch(event.getAction()) { // Check vertical and horizontal touches
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                downX = event.getX();
                downY = event.getY();
                return true;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                upX = event.getX();
                upY = event.getY();

                float deltaX = downX - upX;
                float deltaY = downY - upY;

                //HORIZONTAL SCROLL
                if (Math.abs(deltaX) > Math.abs(deltaY)) {
                    if (Math.abs(deltaX) > min_distance) {
                        // left or right
                        if (deltaX < 0) {
                            this.onLeftToRightSwipe();
                            return true;
                        }
                        if (deltaX > 0) {
                            this.onRightToLeftSwipe();
                            return true;
                        }
                    } else {
                        //not long enough swipe...
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                //VERTICAL SCROLL
                else {
                    if (Math.abs(deltaY) > min_distance) {
                        // top or down
                        if (deltaY < 0) {
                            this.onTopToBottomSwipe();
                            return true;
                        }
                        if (deltaY > 0) {
                            this.onBottomToTopSwipe();
                            return true;
                        }
                    } else {
                        //not long enough swipe...
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void onLeftToRightSwipe(){
        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"left to right",   
                                      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void onRightToLeftSwipe() {
        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"right to left",
                                     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void onTopToBottomSwipe() {
        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"top to bottom", 
                                     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void onBottomToTopSwipe() {
        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"bottom to top", 
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I wrote a simple class that makes it easy to detect the swipe events - TOP, RIGHT, BOTTOM, LEFT.

**1: Detect single swipe event**

```
// Detect and consume specific events
// {Available methods} - detectTop, detectRight, detectBottom, detectLeft
SwipeEvents.detectTop(swipeElement, new SwipeEvents.SwipeSingleCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onSwipe() {
        showToast("Swiped - detectTop");
    }
});
```

**2: Detect any of the swipe events with one callback.**

```
SwipeEvents.detect( swipeElement, new SwipeEvents.SwipeCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onSwipeTop() {
        //Swiped top
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwipeRight() {
        //Swiped right
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwipeBottom() {
        //Swiped bottom
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwipeLeft() {
        //Swiped left
    }
});
```

Here is a blog post with the explanation on how to use: http://bmutinda.com/android-detect-swipe-events/

I have also created a Gist for the code snippets available here: https://gist.github.com/bmutinda/9578f70f1df9bd0687b8

Thanks.

Comment: Ultimate, thanks for sharing this knowledge.

Answer (score 5):

**Left to Right and Right to Left Swipe Detector**

Firstly, declare two variable of float datatype.

```
private float x1, x2;
```

Secondly, wireup your xml view in java. Like I have `ImageView`

```
ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
```

Thirdly, `setOnTouchListener` on your `ImageView`.

```
img.setOnTouchListener(
                    new View.OnTouchListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        switch (event.getAction()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                            x1 = event.getX();
                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            x2 = event.getX();
                            float deltaX = x2 - x1;
                            if (deltaX < 0) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                        "Right to Left swipe",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }else if(deltaX >0){
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                        "Left to Right swipe",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            break;
                        }

                        return false;
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 4):

You should be extend a class from `View.OnTouchListener` and handle the `onTouch` method by overriding it.

```kotlin
interface SwipeListener {
    fun onSwipeLeft()
    fun onSwipeRight()
}

class SwipeGestureListener internal constructor(
    private val listener: SwipeListener,
    private val minDistance: Int = DEFAULT_SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
) : View.OnTouchListener {
    companion object {
        const val DEFAULT_SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 200
    }

    private var anchorX = 0F

    override fun onTouch(view: View, event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        when (event.action) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                anchorX = event.x
                return true
            }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                if (abs(event.x - anchorX) > minDistance) {
                    if (event.x > anchorX) {
                        listener.onSwipeRight()
                    } else {
                        listener.onSwipeLeft()
                    }
                }
                return true
            }
        }
        return view.performClick()
    }
}
```

You can just easily implement it like this in your `Activity` or `Fragment`.

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), SwipeListener {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        viewGroup.setOnTouchListener(SwipeGestureListener(this))
    }

    override fun onSwipeLeft() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Swipe Left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    override fun onSwipeRight() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Swipe Right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I want to add on to the accepted answer which works partially, but is missing the time variable, that makes it perfect.

Simplest left to right swipe detector with a time variable:

In your activity class add following attributes:

```
private float x1,x2;
private long startClickTime;
static final int MIN_DISTANCE = 150;
static final int MAX_SWIPE_TIME = 200;
```

and override onTouchEvent () method:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
    {
        switch(event.getAction())
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                startClickTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
                x1 = event.getX();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                long clickDuration = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() - startClickTime;
                x2 = event.getX();
                float deltaX = x2 - x1;
                if (Math.abs(deltaX) > MIN_DISTANCE && clickDuration < MAX_SWIPE_TIME)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "left2right swipe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
                }
                else
                {
                    // consider as something else - a screen tap for example
                }
                break;
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I think what you want is called a fling. The MotionEvents can be used to determine the direction of the fling.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements  GestureDetector.OnGestureListener {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.stellar_layout);
        mDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent event1, MotionEvent event2,
                           float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        Log.d(tag, "onFling:\n " + event1.toString()+ "\n " + event2.toString());
        /* prints the following
            MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, id[0]=0, x[0]=297.0, y[0]=672.0, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=488341979, downTime=488341979, deviceId=6, source=0x1002 }
            MotionEvent { action=ACTION_UP, id[0]=0, x[0]=560.0, y[0]=583.0, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=488342047, downTime=488341979, deviceId=6, source=0x1002 }
        */
        return true;
    }

}
```

http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html

Answer (score 2):

Detect swipe in four direction

```
private float x1,x2,y1,y2;
static final int MIN_DISTANCE = 70;
```

and

```
switch(pSceneTouchEvent.getAction())
     {
       case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
           x1 = pSceneTouchEvent.getX();     
           y1 = pSceneTouchEvent.getY();
       break;         
       case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
           x2 = pSceneTouchEvent.getX();
           y2 = pSceneTouchEvent.getY();
           float deltaX = x2 - x1;
           float deltaY = y2 - y1;
           if (deltaX > MIN_DISTANCE)
           {
               swipeLeftToRight();
           }
           else if( Math.abs(deltaX) > MIN_DISTANCE)
           {
               swipeRightToLeft();
           } 
           else if(deltaY > MIN_DISTANCE){
               swipeTopToBottom();
           } 
           else if( Math.abs(deltaY) > MIN_DISTANCE){
               swipeBottopmToTop();
           }

       break;   
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

this should help you maybe...

```
private final GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener onGestureListener = new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
        Log.i("gestureDebug333", "doubleTapped:" + e);
        return super.onDoubleTap(e);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        Log.i("gestureDebug333", "doubleTappedEvent:" + e);

        return super.onDoubleTapEvent(e);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        Log.i("gestureDebug333", "onDown:" + e);


        return super.onDown(e);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {


        Log.i("gestureDebug333", "flinged:" + e1 + "---" + e2);
        Log.i("gestureDebug333", "fling velocity:" + velocityX + "---" + velocityY);
        if (e1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN && e1.getX() > (e2.getX() + 300)){
           // Toast.makeText(context, "flinged right to left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            goForward();
        }
        if (e1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN && e2.getX() > (e1.getX() + 300)){
            //Toast.makeText(context, "flinged left to right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            goBack();
        }
        return super.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
        super.onLongPress(e);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        return super.onScroll(e1, e2, distanceX, distanceY);
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
        super.onShowPress(e);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
        return super.onSingleTapConfirmed(e);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        return super.onSingleTapUp(e);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to catch the event from the starting of the swipe you can use MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE and store the first value to compare

```
private float upX1;
private float upX2;
private float upY1;
private float upY2;
private boolean isTouchCaptured = false;
static final int min_distance = 100;


        viewObject.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                        downX = event.getX();
                        downY = event.getY();

                        if (!isTouchCaptured) {
                            upX1 = event.getX();
                            upY1 = event.getY();
                            isTouchCaptured = true;
                        } else {
                            upX2 = event.getX();
                            upY2 = event.getY();

                            float deltaX = upX1 - upX2;
                            float deltaY = upY1 - upY2;
                            //HORIZONTAL SCROLL
                            if (Math.abs(deltaX) > Math.abs(deltaY)) {
                                if (Math.abs(deltaX) > min_distance) {
                                    // left or right
                                    if (deltaX < 0) {

                                        return true;
                                    }
                                    if (deltaX > 0) {
                                        return true;
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    //not long enough swipe...
                                    return false;
                                }
                            }
                            //VERTICAL SCROLL
                            else {
                                if (Math.abs(deltaY) > min_distance) {
                                    // top or down
                                    if (deltaY < 0) {

                                        return false;
                                    }
                                    if (deltaY > 0) {

                                        return false;
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    //not long enough swipe...
                                    return false;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                        isTouchCaptured = false;
                    }
                }
                return false;

            }
        });
```

Comment: let's say i have a Toast like `Toast.makeText(MainAcivity.this, "top to down" + increaseValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` her how do make a single swipe to add values min=0 and max=10.

Answer (score 1):

After a full day working on this feature finally able to get the right answer.

> First, create the following classes:

```
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

/**
 * Created by hoshyar on 1/19/17.
 */

public class SwipeDetector implements View.OnTouchListener {

    public static enum Action {
        LR, // Left to Right
        RL, // Right to Left
        TB, // Top to bottom
        BT, // Bottom to Top
        None // when no action was detected
    }

    private static final String logTag = "Swipe";
    private static final int MIN_DISTANCE = 100;
    private float downX, downY, upX, upY;
    private Action mSwipeDetected = Action.None;

    public boolean swipeDetected() {
        return mSwipeDetected != Action.None;
    }

    public Action getAction() {
        return mSwipeDetected;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                downX = event.getX();
                downY = event.getY();
                mSwipeDetected = Action.None;
                return false;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                upX = event.getX();
                upY = event.getY();

                float deltaX = downX - upX;
                float deltaY = downY - upY;
                Log.i(logTag,String.valueOf(deltaX));
                Log.i(logTag,String.valueOf(deltaX));

                if (deltaY>0 && deltaY<10 && deltaX<0 || deltaY==0 && deltaX>-15 && deltaX<0){
                    Log.i(logTag,"to right");
                }if (deltaY>=0 && deltaY<10 && deltaX>0 || deltaY<0 && deltaX>15 && deltaX<40){
                Log.i(logTag,"to left");
            }





                if (Math.abs(deltaX) > MIN_DISTANCE) {
                    // left or right
                    if (deltaX < 0) {
                        mSwipeDetected = Action.LR;
                        return false;
                    }
                    if (deltaX > 0) {


                        mSwipeDetected = Action.RL;
                        return false;
                    }
                } else if (Math.abs(deltaY) > MIN_DISTANCE) {


                    if (deltaY < 0) {
                        Log.i(logTag,"to bottom");
                        mSwipeDetected = Action.TB;
                        return false;
                    }
                    if (deltaY > 0) {
                        Log.i(logTag,"to up");
                        mSwipeDetected = Action.BT;
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

> Finally on the object that you want to apply.
>   My example:

```
SwipeDetector swipeDetector = new SwipeDetector();
listView.setOnTouchListener(swipeDetector);
```

Good luck .

Comment: but how to return the event to the class?

Answer (score 1):

here is generic swipe left detector for any view in kotlin using databinding

```
@BindingAdapter("onSwipeLeft")
fun View.setOnSwipeLeft(runnable: Runnable) {
    setOnTouchListener(object : View.OnTouchListener {
        var x0 = 0F; var y0 = 0F; var t0 = 0L
        val defaultClickDuration = 200

        override fun onTouch(v: View?, motionEvent: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
            motionEvent?.let { event ->
                when(event.action) {
                    MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                        x0 = event.x; y0 = event.y; t0 = System.currentTimeMillis()
                    }
                    MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                        val x1 = event.x; val y1 = event.y; val t1 = System.currentTimeMillis()

                        if (x0 == x1 && y0 == y1 && (t1 - t0) < defaultClickDuration) {
                            performClick()
                            return false
                        }
                        if (x0 > x1) { runnable.run() }
                    }
                    else -> {}
                }
            }
            return true
        }
    })
}
```

and then to use it in your layout:

```
app:onSwipeLeft="@{() -> viewModel.swipeLeftHandler()}"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TransferMarket extends Activity {

    float x1,x2;
    float y1, y2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_transfer_market);
    }

    // onTouchEvent () method gets called when User performs any touch event on screen

    // Method to handle touch event like left to right swap and right to left swap

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent touchevent)
    {
        switch (touchevent.getAction())
        {
            // when user first touches the screen we get x and y coordinate
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            {
                x1 = touchevent.getX();
                y1 = touchevent.getY();
                break;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            {
                x2 = touchevent.getX();
                y2 = touchevent.getY();

                //if left to right sweep event on screen
                if (x1 < x2)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Left to Right Swap Performed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                // if right to left sweep event on screen
                if (x1 > x2)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Right to Left Swap Performed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                // if UP to Down sweep event on screen
                if (y1 < y2)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "UP to Down Swap Performed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                //if Down to UP sweep event on screen
                if (y1 > y2)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Down to UP Swap Performed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Use Only x co-ordinates that is enough for left to right and vice versa

Answer (score 0):

the best answer is @Gal Rom 's. there is more information about it:
touch event return's to child views first. and if you define onClick or onTouch listener for them, parnt view (for example fragment) will not receive any touch listener. So if you want define swipe listener for fragment in this situation, you must implement it in a new class:

```
    package com.neganet.QRelations.fragments;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

public class SwipeListenerFragment extends FrameLayout {
    private float x1,x2;
    static final int MIN_DISTANCE=150;
    private onSwipeEventDetected mSwipeDetectedListener;


    public SwipeListenerFragment(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SwipeListenerFragment(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SwipeListenerFragment(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        boolean result=false;
        switch(ev.getAction())
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                x1 = ev.getX();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                x2 = ev.getX();
                float deltaX = x2 - x1;
                if (Math.abs(deltaX) > MIN_DISTANCE)
                {
                    if(deltaX<0)
                    {
                        result=true;
                        if(mSwipeDetectedListener!=null)
                            mSwipeDetectedListener.swipeLeftDetected();

                    }else if(deltaX>0){
                        result=true;
                        if(mSwipeDetectedListener!=null)
                            mSwipeDetectedListener.swipeRightDetected();
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public interface onSwipeEventDetected
    {
        public void swipeLeftDetected();
        public void swipeRightDetected();

    }

    public void registerToSwipeEvents(onSwipeEventDetected listener)
    {
        this.mSwipeDetectedListener=listener;
    }
}
```

I changed @Gal Rom 's class. So it can detect both right and left swipe and specially it returns onInterceptTouchEvent true after detect. its important because if we dont do it some times child views maybe receive event and both of Swipe for fragment and onClick for child view (for example) runs and cause some issues. 
after making this class, you must change your fragment xml file:

```
    <com.neganet.QRelations.fragments.SwipeListenerFragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/main_list_layout"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context="com.neganet.QRelations.fragments.mainList"
    android:background="@color/main_frag_back">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/farazList"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical" />
</com.neganet.QRelations.fragments.SwipeListenerFragment>
```

you see that begin tag is the class that we made. now in fragment class:

```
            View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_list, container, false);
        SwipeListenerFragment tdView=(SwipeListenerFragment) view;
        tdView.registerToSwipeEvents(this);


and then Implement SwipeListenerFragment.onSwipeEventDetected in it:

        @Override
    public void swipeLeftDetected() {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void swipeRightDetected() {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

It's a little complicated but works perfect :)

Answer (score 0):

Short and easy version:

**1. First create this abstract class**

```
public abstract class HorizontalSwipeListener implements View.OnTouchListener {

    private float firstX;
    private int minDistance;

    HorizontalSwipeListener(int minDistance) {
        this.minDistance = minDistance;
    }

    abstract void onSwipeRight();

    abstract void onSwipeLeft();

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                firstX = event.getX();
                return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                float secondX = event.getX();
                if (Math.abs(secondX - firstX) > minDistance) {
                    if (secondX > firstX) {
                        onSwipeLeft();
                    } else {
                        onSwipeRight();
                    }
                }
                return true;
        }
        return view.performClick();
    }

}
```

**2.Then create a concrete class implementing what you need:**

```
public class SwipeListener extends HorizontalSwipeListener {

    public SwipeListener() {
        super(200);
    }

    @Override
    void onSwipeRight() {
        System.out.println("right");
    }

    @Override
    void onSwipeLeft() {
        System.out.println("left");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

to detect swipe gestures specifically for left or right movements in Android, you can use gesture detection provided by the `GestureDetector` class

you can use this code :

```
 val gestureListener = object : GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
    private val SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100
    private val SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100

    override fun onFling(
        e1: MotionEvent,
        e2: MotionEvent,
        velocityX: Float,
        velocityY: Float
    ): Boolean {
        val deltaX = e2.x - e1.x
        val deltaY = e2.y - e1.y

        if (Math.abs(deltaX) > Math.abs(deltaY)
            && Math.abs(deltaX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD
            && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD
        ) {
            if (deltaX > 0) {
                // Swipe right detected
            } else {
                // Swipe left detected
            }
            return true
        }

        return false
    }
}
```

also :

```
val gestureDetector = GestureDetector(this, gestureListener)

view.setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
    gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)
    true // Return 'true' to indicate that you're consuming the touch event
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use gesture detector. Do not use constant in pixel.

```
public class ActivityBase extends Activity {
    private GestureDetector detector;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        detector = new GestureDetector( this, new GestureDetector.OnGestureListener(){

            @Override
            public boolean onFling( MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY ){
                //get activity window width
                float width = 0;
                View rootView = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
                if( rootView != null ){
                    width = rootView.getWidth();
                }
                final float threshold = 0.3f; // 30%, you can change it
                float dx = Math.abs( e1.getX()-e2.getX());
                if( dx > Math.abs( e1.getY()-e2.getY()) && dx > width*threshold ){
                    //swipe left or right here
                }
                return false;
            }
        } );
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent( MotionEvent event ){
        detector.onTouchEvent( event );
        return super.onTouchEvent( event );
    }
}
```