# Drag and drop in ScrollView

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, scrollview

I have some ImageViews inside a HorizontalScrollView.

I would like to be able to drag and drop the ImageViews somewhere else, but still maintain scrolling capability. Dragging should only be activated when the user starts a mostly vertical motion with their finger.

For now, I have drag and drop activate on long-press, but that is not a good solution.

To illustrate:
[image: Drag and Drop]

Comment: Have you looked at GestureOverlayView? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/gesture/GestureOverlayView.html

Comment: How would you suggest I implement it? Switch off touch intercept for the ScrollView, then detect what kind of gesture with the GestureOverlayView?

Answer (score 2):

I had to do exactly this as well. After reading http://techin-android.blogspot.in/2011/11/swipe-event-in-android-scrollview.html I adapted the code as follows:

```
class MyOnTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {
    static final int MIN_DISTANCE_Y = 40;

    private float downY, upY;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                downY = event.getY();
                return true;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                upY = event.getY();

                float deltaY = downY - upY;

                // swipe vertical?
                if (Math.abs(deltaY) > MIN_DISTANCE_Y) {
                    if (deltaY < 0) {
                        //Start your drag here if appropriate
                        return true;
                    }
                    if (deltaY > 0) {
                        //Or start your drag here if appropriate
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

And then set the listener on the `ImageView`s:

```
            imageView.setOnTouchListener(new MyOnTouchListener());
```

In this version of the code I am only checking for movement in the vertical direction (I also changed the minimum movement to be 40 instead of 100 as in the original code). If a vertical movement is detected, the specific `ImageView` can begin to drag or do any other actions you want. If a vertical movement is not detected, the `ImageView`'s `MyTouchListener` returns `false` which means the `ImageView` does not consume the touch event. This allows the parent `ScrollView` to eventually get the touch event and consume it (for scroll detection). The answers here are helpful for understanding touch events: [MotionEvent handling in ScrollView in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12884250/motionevent-handling-in-scrollview-in-android).