# Extend GridView / DetailFragment with ViewPager (for lateral navigation)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-gridview, android-cursorloader

I'm trying to add a `ViewPager` (using FragmentStatePagerAdapter) to my current app. What I've got so far, is a master/detail setup, where the master is a `GridView` and the detail is (essentially) an `ImageView`. I'm using a `CursorLoader` to load a cursor, and "connect" it to the grid view using a `CursorAdapter`.

Click an image in the grid, and `MainActivity` starts a `DetailActivity` with the corresponding IMAGE_ID in an URI. The `DetailFragment`, in turn, has its own `CursorLoader` to get that specific image and set it in the UI.

Nice stuff, except the user has to go **back-and-forth** to switch images. I obviously want to be able to swipe left and right (on an image/detailview) to jump to previous/next image! This -- I've learned -- is where a `ViewPager` comes into play.

**I found a [nice tutorial](http://www.appsrox.com/android/tutorials/showcase/9/), but I'm a bit confused as to how this all "meshes" with my [current code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33106813/adding-prev-next-buttons-to-detail-fragment-of-master-detail-activity).** As I said, I have a CursorAdapter which populates the GridView. I take it I'll be keeping that, unchanged? However, my DetailFragment is where I understand I'll be needing some new code. 
Some thoughts and questions, then:

- The tutorial's `ItemPagerFragment` uses a custom adapter, `CursorPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter`. This is to "pre-load" the detail fragments, and handle the swipes and lateral navigation. I need to *add* this to my project (but this does not replace my CursorAdapter)?
- The `ItemPagerFragment` in the tutorial has a CursorLoader, and I'm not sure what that actually does. However, at a glance, I would assume the task of this loader is to get *all* images, such that the fragment can (somehow) "prepare" all the "pages" (ItemDetailFragments -- see below) the user can navigate between?
- The `ItemPagerFragment` in the tutorial "holds" the FragmentStatePagerAdapter, and inflates the `ViewPager` UI. I'm thinking I'll need to *add* such a class to my app, with a CursorLoader to load *all* images in the `MediaStore`.
- Each "page" of detail view (images) is then an instance of `ItemDetailFragment`. As I understand, this is equivalent to [my current DetailFragment.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33106813/adding-prev-next-buttons-to-detail-fragment-of-master-detail-activity) It takes an ID or an index/position (or something) and loads the corresponding image into the ImageView (using a ContentLoader from the `MediaStore`).
- But how do I handle the user clicking a specific image in the gridview, to load it? The CursorPagerAdapter's `getItem()` method returns an `ItemDetailFragment`, so maybe I could use this to get the desired fragment? But how to pass in (request) the specific image_id?