# Can View Pager have two swipe inputs

Tags: android, android-viewpager, swipe

I have Implemented both horizontal and vertical view pager which work 
Horizontal (swipe side ways left and right) only or 
Vertical (swipe Up and down) only.

But I need to catch both the swipe inputs, if swiped either way the view pager should work. in single direction.

i.e : if swiped up and down the Pages should go up and down,
if swiped left and right also it should go up and down only.

EDIT: Can I override any methods of view pager to get both the swipe inputs.

Comment: check this library https://github.com/alexzaitsev/freepager

Comment: @MalekHijazi Yeah I have gone through it, but as I explained above, the page transition should be done in single direction only.

Comment: you can override touch events. and calculate touch gestures and check if swipe is from left to right, top, bottom.

Comment: @HammadTariqSahi can  give me any reference or do u  want me to post the code which I try?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13095494/how-to-detect-swipe-direction-between-left-right-and-up-down

Answer (score 0):

first of all you have to detect swipe detection.

[check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6645537/how-to-detect-the-swipe-left-or-right-in-android)

And then implement your view pager based on swipe.