# Slide finger vertically to open fragments

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-viewpager

I would like to achieve fragments navigation like this:
[image]

When I slide finger down somewhere on fragment A, fragment C will be opened (as slide movement), to go back to A slide finger up from C and so on...

I thought about custom ViewPager with vertical swipe direction but I have problem with "Open .." triangles, it should be shared between fragments end rotated during slide movement to change from for example "Open C" to "Open A". Any suggestions ? :)

Comment: "I thought about custom ViewPager with vertical swipe direction but I have problem with "Open .." triangles" - this would have have been a better question, seeing as this is a actual coding issue, I'm sure that most people would suggest a `ViewPager`, as "out-of-the-box" it has callbacks for scrolling, and is designed for flipping through Fragments ..

Comment: You might be able to do the rotation in a PageTransformer.

Comment: A combination of both comments should work: `ViewPager2` (forget the old `ViewPager`) to achieve stable vertical paging. And `PageTransformer` to put the `Open` Views in between the fragments. Vertical paging with the old `ViewPager` is not working propery, because the private `slope` parameter is not well-set for different screen sizes (it's only good for hotizontal swipes). This is fixed with `ViewPager2` (amongst other issues).

Answer (score 2):

Create `anim` folder in `res` folder.
Create file named in_up

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="-100%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="700"/>
```

Create another file named out_down

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="-100%"
        android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="700"/>
```

To detect swipe left and right you can use this code.

Create variables

```
private float y1,y2;
static final int MIN_DISTANCE = 150;
```

And override `onTouchEvent()`.

```
  @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
  
    switch(event.getAction())
    {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            y1 = event.getY();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            y2 = event.getY();
            float deltaY = y2 - y1;
            if (Math.abs(deltaY) > MIN_DISTANCE)
            {
                 MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
                 myFragment.show(this.getSupportFragmentManager(), "my fragment");
                 overridePendingTransition(R.anim.in_up, R.anim.out_down);
            }
            break;
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: it's working! but can you tell me how to do that for left to right swiping

Comment: you can see this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/22091163/14837619

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do:

1. Use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26387629/7833945) to listen to swipes
2. Make some adjustments to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33992609/7833945) , like enter_from_left would become enter_from_top and code inside changes from:

   ```
       android:fromXDelta="-100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
       android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
       android:duration="700"/>
   ```

   to

   ```
      android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="0%"
      android:fromYDelta="-100%" android:toYDelta="0%"
      android:duration="700"/>
   ```

   And make similar changes to other transition xml files.
3. Check which page I am on and accordingly call `replaceFragmentWithAnimation` when a swipe is detected.

Answer (score 0):

i recommend to simply use [Viewpager2](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/viewpager2) instead of the legacy ViewPager as ViewPager2 uses the recyclerview implementation under the hood so it supports vertical and horizontal swiping. check the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/vp2-migration#nested-scrollables) to understand how to migrate from ViewPager to ViewPager2